# Forward Squid Traffic To Tor Network

Tags: ssh, proxy, squid

I have installed squid on my Ubuntu machine and I would like to forward requests from the squid proxy to the Tor network. Is this possible without iptable changes? I know that Tor proxies are socks proxies on the client end.

Comment: "Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity." I fail to see how this falls into "Professional".

Comment: I fail to see how setting up something to connect to Tor network losses "Professional" title. Or maybe its just me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that it wont be possible using Squid alone. I installed privoxy and set it up in between Squid and the Tor network. Privoxy has  built-in capability to connect to a socks proxy.